# does git store diff information in commit objects?

Tags: git, diff

According to [this](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html):

> It is important to note that this is very different from most SCM 
>       systems that you may be familiar with. Subversion, CVS, Perforce, 
>       Mercurial and the like all use Delta Storage systems - they store 
>       the differences between one commit and the next. Git does not do 
>       this - it stores a snapshot of what all the files in your project 
>       look like in this tree structure each time you commit. This is a 
>       very important concept to understand when using Git.

Yet when I run `git show $SHA1ofCommitObject`...

```
commit 4405aa474fff8247607d0bf599e054173da84113
Author: Joe Smoe <joe.smoe@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 1 08:48:21 2012 -0500

    First commit

diff --git a/index.html b/index.html
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..de8b69b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/index.html
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+<h1>Hello World!</h1>
diff --git a/interests/chess.html b/interests/chess.html
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e5be7dd
--- /dev/null
+++ b/interests/chess.html
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Did you see on Slashdot that King's Gambit accepted is solved! <a href="http://game
```

... it outputs the diff of the commit with the previous commits. I know that git doesn't store diffs in blob objects, but does it store diffs in commit objects? Or is `git show` dynamically calculating the diff?

Comment: A side note: Git does actually delta-compress objects, but it's just for the sake of compression. People sometimes misunderstand this as saying Git stores diffs. There's some documentation of the format here: http://book.git-scm.com/7_the_packfile.html (Keep in mind that the objects it records deltas between are  just blobs of data that it discovered were similar; they aren't necessarily consecutive versions of the same file, though they could be. And of course, the deltas aren't line-by-line diffs.)

Comment: Updating the very relevant link from Jefromi: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, commit objects in git don't contain diffs - instead, each commit object contains a hash of the tree, which recursively and completely defines the content of the source tree at that commit.  There's a [nice explanation in the git community book](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of what goes into blob objects, tree objects and commit objects .

All the diffs that are shown to you by git's tools are calculated on demand from the complete content of files.

Answer (score 94):

What the statement means is that, most other version control systems need a point of reference in the past to be able to re-create the current commit.

For example, at some point in the past, a diff-based VCS (version control system) would have stored a full snapshot:

```
x = snapshot
+ = diff
History:
x-----+-----+-----+-----(+) Where we are now
```

So, in such a scenario, to re-create the state at (now), it would have to checkout (x) and then apply diffs for each (+) until it gets to now. Note that it would extremely inefficient to store deltas forever, so every so often, delta based VCSes store a full snapshot. [Here's how its done for subversion](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/master-passphrase/notes/skip-deltas).

Now, git is different. Git stores references to complete blobs and this means that with git, **only one commit is sufficient to recreate the codebase at that point in time**. Git does not need to look up information from past revisions to create a snapshot.

So if that is the case, then where does the delta compression that git uses come in?

Well, it is nothing but a compression concept - there is no point storing the same information twice, if only a tiny amount has changed. Therefore, represent what has changed, but store a reference to it, so that the commit that it belongs to, which is in effect a tree of references, can still be re-created without looking at past commits. The thing is, though, that Git does not do this immediately after every commit, but rather on a garbage collection run. So, if git has not run its garbage collection, you can see objects in your index with very similar content.

However, when Git runs its garbage collection (or when you call `git gc` manually), then the duplicates are cleaned up and a read only pack file is created. You don't have to worry about running garbage collection manually - git contains heuristics which tell it when to do so.

Comment: Thank you, Carl. So committing minor changes in a huge project does not inflate the repository with lots of redundant copies (at least in the long run)?

Comment: @shuhalo That's right, though it is even better than that. If you made a copy of all your source files and added them to your current commit, the only additional information after a gc run would be the metadata - filenames, paths, author and such. The actual contents of the files themselves would simply refer to the blobs in the past that came from the original code.

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t understand your wording. Can you make an edit for: ‘ Well, it is nothing but a compression concept - there is no point storing the same information twice, if only a tiny amount has changed. Therefore, represent what has changed’ Are you saying if on a 10k line file, if I add one character then a new hash isn’t generated it?! It’s just super unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

1. A Commit is a small metadata **file**. It contains all the information to restore a **full snapshot** of your project.
2. Some commands, such as `diff` or `cherry-pick`, **compute** differences between snapshots.