# Why does Delta Lake seem to store so much redundant information?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, delta-lake

I just started using delta lake so my mental model might be off - I'm asking this question to validate/refute it.

My understanding of delta lake is that it only stores *incremental* changes to data (the "deltas"). Kind of like git - every time you make a commit, you're not storing an entire snapshot of the codebase - a commit only contains the changes you made.
Similarly, I would imagine that if I create a Delta table and then I attempt to "update" the table with everything it already contains (i.e. an "empty commit") then I would not expect to see any new data created as a result of that update.

However this is **not** what I observe: such an update appears to duplicate the existing table. What's going on? That doesn't seem very "incremental" to me.

(I'll replace the actual UUID values in the filenames for readability)

```py
# create the data
dataGen = sc._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.DataGenerator()
inserts = sc._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.convertToStringList(dataGen.generateInserts(200))
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inserts, 2))

delta_base_path = "s3://my-delta-table/test"
(df.write.format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save(delta_base_path))
```

```
!aws s3 ls --recursive s3://my-delta-table/test

2020-10-19 14:33:21       1622 test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json
2020-10-19 14:33:18          0 test/_delta_log_$folder$
2020-10-19 14:33:19      10790 test/part-00000-UUID1-c000.snappy.parquet
2020-10-19 14:33:19      10795 test/part-00001-UUID2-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Then I overwrite using the exact same dataset:

```
(df.write.format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save(delta_base_path))

!aws s3 ls --recursive s3://my-delta-table/test
2020-10-19 14:53:02       1620 test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json
2020-10-19 14:53:08        872 test/_delta_log/00000000000000000001.json
2020-10-19 14:53:01          0 test/_delta_log_$folder$
2020-10-19 14:53:07       6906 test/part-00000-UUID1-c000.snappy.parquet
2020-10-19 14:53:01       6906 test/part-00000-UUID3-c000.snappy.parquet
2020-10-19 14:53:07       6956 test/part-00001-UUID2-c000.snappy.parquet
2020-10-19 14:53:01       6956 test/part-00001-UUID4-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Now there are TWO `part-0` and `part-1`s, of the exact same size. Why doesn't Delta dedupe the existing data?

Comment: FYI: Git stores a full version of every changed file with every commit, it does [not just store the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398744/does-git-store-diff-information-in-commit-objects). Surprising, I know :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not completely correct understanding - Delta won't check the existing data for duplicates automatically - if you want to store only new/updated data, then you need to use [`merge` operation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#conditional-update-without-overwrite) that will check for existing data, and then you can decide what you'll do with existing data - overwrite with new data, or just ignore that.

You may find more information on the Delta's site, or in the 9th chapter of the Learning Spark, 2ed book (it's [freely available from Databricks](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly))